# How to return a special text color from a QAbstractItemModel depending on its widget being enabled/disabled

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractitemview

For some columns in my `QAbstractItemModel`, I need the text to appear in a special color.  I am doing this by returning that color in `data()` where `role == Qt::TextColorRole`.  This is fine, until the view that displays this model is disabled, then those special colors are still 'bright' while all other text is gray/muted.

Is there a simple way to return a special color for when a widget is disabled?

Ideas that have failed (or are too complicated):

1. Return a QPalette form `data()` with the right color for enabled/disabled - does not work (nor is it documented to)
2. Check `QAbstractItemModel::flags()` - base class does not know about widget either (nor should it)
3. Connect a signal from my widget to my model to emit whenever the enabled/disabled state of the widget changes.

Number 3 seems most likely, but it is a bit complicated.  For what it is worth, I will only have a single item view using this model at a time.

Desired Code:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    switch (role)
    {
        case Qt::TextColorRole:
            if (isSpecialIndex(index))
            {
                // Does not work
                // Nor does returning a QPalette
                return QPair<QColor, QColor>(enabledColor, disabledColor);
            }
            return QVariant();
    }
}
```

What I'll probably have to do (am hoping for a better solution):

```
void MyModel::onPartnerWidgetEnableStatusUpdate(bool enabled)
{
    beginResetModel();
    m_partnerEnabled = enabled;
    endResetModel();
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    switch (role)
    {
        case Qt::TextColorRole:
            if (isSpecialIndex(index))
            {
                return m_partnerEnabled ? enabledColor : disabledColor;
            }
            return QVariant();
    }
}

// http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop
void MyWidget::changeEvent(QEvent* event) // override
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::EnabledChange)
    {
        // or emit a signal hooked to the model
        m_model.onPartnerWidgetEnableStatusUpdate(isEnabled());
    }

    QWidget::changeEvent(event);
}
```

Naturally, this would not work with multiple views on a single model.

Comment: I've taken the approach of #3 to accomplish similar effects with QML, but the ideas are still the same; it seems straightforward. Why don't you try something and then post your progress; that can lead to more specific questions which may help.

Comment: I've thought of a solution that _should_ work:

Have a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` whose constructor takes a widget - its parent.  There would be a delegate instance for each widget.  The delegate can then ignore the `Qt::TextColorRole` data from the model when drawing text on a disabled widget.